# Variables undefined in Python

Tags: python, variables, undefined

I'm aware there are similar threads out there for this, I'm just having a hard time understanding.

I keep getting an error saying "Lvl" is undefined as a variable.  I'm assuming it's because I need to pass a variables from initstatswarrior() to selectclass().  However, I'm not sure, as it's been years since I worked with Python.  Any tips would be appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\rpg\start.py", line 48, in <module>
    selectclass()
File "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\rpg\start.py", line 17, in selectclass
    Level 1       """, Lvl, """
NameError: name 'Lvl' is not defined

import os

def cls():
    os.system ("CLS")

def namecharacter():
    cls()
    playername = input("Character Name: ")
    print ("You shall be called", playername, "in the realm.\n")
    input("Press Enter to continue...")

def selectclass():
    cls()
    print("""Here are your current stats:

    -----------------
    Level 1       """, Lvl, """
    -----------------
    Hit Points:   """, HP, """
    Skill Points: """, SP, """ 
    Armor:        """, AC, """
    -----------------
    Attack:       """, Atk, """
    Accuracy:     """, Acc, """
    Mind:         """, Mind, """
    Evade:        """, Evade, """  
    Defense:      """, Def, """
    Charisma:     """, Cha, """
    -----------------
    """)

    input("Press Enter to continue...")

def initstatswarrior():
    HP = 100
    SP = 40
    AC = 60
    Atk = 11
    Acc = 11
    Mind = 8
    Evade = 8
    Def = 13
    Cha = 9


    namecharacter()
    initstatswarrior()
    selectclass()
```

Thank you!

Comment: `Lvl` is only used once in your code, and it's a reference, not an assignment. How do you think that works? Also, as I say in my profile, RPGs are a poor choice for beginner programming projects, because you end up doing a lot of work to learn very little about programming.

Comment: The fist thing to do would be to properly indent the code in the question so we can actually tell what's happening.

Comment: Indenting was modified for the post.  I'll try to edit it.  Thanks

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly indent code in question.

Comment: always add in question full error message (Traceback) - there are may usefull information - ie. which line makes problem.

Comment: added error messages, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't assigned any to value to Lvl so you get an error. You may want to do it like this:

```
import os

def cls():
    os.system ("CLS")

def namecharacter():
    cls()
    playername = input("Character Name: ")
    print ("You shall be called", playername, "in the realm.\n")
    input("Press Enter to continue...")

def selectclass():
    cls()
    Lvl = 1
    HP = 100
    SP = 40
    AC = 60
    Atk = 11
    Acc = 11
    Mind = 8
    Evade = 8
    Def = 13
    Cha = 9
    print("""Here are your current stats:

    -----------------
    Level         """, Lvl, """
    -----------------
    Hit Points:   """, HP, """
    Skill Points: """, SP, """
    Armor:        """, AC, """
    -----------------
    Attack:       """, Atk, """
    Accuracy:     """, Acc, """
    Mind:         """, Mind, """
    Evade:        """, Evade, """
    Defense:      """, Def, """
    Charisma:     """, Cha, """
    -----------------
    """)

    input("Press Enter to continue...")


namecharacter()
selectclass()
```

Output:

```
Character Name: x
You shall be called x in the realm.

Press Enter to continue...
Here are your current stats:

    -----------------
    Level          1 
    -----------------
    Hit Points:    100 
    Skill Points:  40 
    Armor:         60 
    -----------------
    Attack:        11 
    Accuracy:      11 
    Mind:          8 
    Evade:         8 
    Defense:       13 
    Charisma:      9 
    -----------------

Press Enter to continue...
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot.  Eliminates the headache of the extra function.  Thank you

Comment: Hmm I'm getting the same error messages.  I wonder if there is an issue with my syntax

Comment: Have you tried copy pasting this code? I tested it out and it works.

Comment: Perfect!  I forgot to hit Save in Notepad+++.  Lol.  I appreciate your help.  Thank you

Comment: @BrandonJ.Wood on SO there is no function to mark this as solved - you can only accept this answer.